# Selecting translate option from right click menu in Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am trying to translate the page to English by clicking on translate option from right click browser menu. So far, my code is doing the right click, but I am not able to select the translate option.

Code:

```
console.log('Then I should right click on screen')
browser.sleep(3000);
browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.id('search-icon'))).perform();
browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform().then(function () {
    console.log('Is right click performed ?');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right Click and clicking on the translate on the browser generated menu is an event that protractor/selenium doesn't support. Instead if you know the position of the `translate` option on the menu generated by right click, then you can use `arrow` keys to navigate to it and then press `enter` or `return` key. Here's how -

Suppose if the `translate` option is 3rd in the menu, then send the `ARROW_DOWN` key thrice -

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.id('search-icon'))).perform();
browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).sendKeys(protractor.Key.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(protractor.Key.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(protractor.Key.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(protractor.Key.RETURN).perform().then(function () {
    browser.sleep(3000);
    console.log('Clicked on translate');
});
```

Hope it helps