# Protractor : How to select an item from list when right-clicked

Tags: select, protractor

I am trying to Right click on an element and then select an option "Rename" from the list. I have got "right clicking" working but can't select option from the list. Referred links [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025244/selecting-translate-option-from-right-click-menu-in-protractor), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750222/selenium-webdriver-how-to-select-from-list-menu-item)

Note 1:

1: On right click the menu options that are visible are native context menus. So, they don't appear in my DOM that I can see.

2: The App runs only in Chrome browser(not sure if it is a browser issue)

I have tried the following code:

```
 browser.actions().mouseMove(elementVar).perform();
 browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).click(protractor.Button.ARROW_DOWN).click(protractor.Button.ARROW_DOWN).click(protractor.Button.ARROW_DOWN).perform();
```

Consider, "Rename" to be the third option in the list.

Note 2:
If I am just running the app and enter 'R' from my keyboard, it selects the "Rename" option. But when I tried to run it in my test, it doesn't select the "Rename" option. See below code I tried:

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(elementVar).perform();
browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.ARROW_RIGHT).sendKeys('R',protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
```

None of the above code works. Let me know if more information is required.

EDIT:

I am guessing the following to be happening:

once I mouse over, the script "right clicks" and after that the "tooltip" is displayed. Since the "tooltip" is displayed after "right click" I think the menu list goes to the background(the list is still visible along with the tool-tip), which is why the arrow down keys aren't working. Is this possible? If yes, how can I wait for the tooltip to be invisible and then right click?

Input: I tried to wait for tool-tip to be invisible and then right click, but still the "Arrow_down" doesn't work.

**Is there a way to bring the menu list in the front once we have right clicked?**

**IMPORTANT**:

I took a screenshot after I right clicked on the element, and the screenshot doesn't show the "menu list". Below is the code for screenshot:

```
    browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform()
     .then(function() {
         browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(screenShot) {
            writeScreenShot(screenShot, "image.png");
});
});

//writeScreenShot takes two variables actual screenshot data and the file name. And the screenshot is saved as "image.png"
```

What needs to be done?

Comment: did you try clicking the element first?

Comment: Yes I tried with clicking on the element first, no luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select an item from "context list Menu" - protrator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34054640/how-to-select-an-item-from-context-list-menu-protrator)

Comment: @alecxe: Yes the the other link is also posted by me since this thread went inactive, also added some more information based on my new research and refined my question. The answer posted here didn't work for my problem. Let me know how can I close this issue or you want me to do anything else.

Comment: @FindABug I understand and no offence, but posting a duplicate question because there is no activity here is not acceptable on SO. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @alecxe. Won't happen again. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you send `ARROW` keys to the browser, you have to send them as keys instead of passing them to `click()` function and the `ARROW_DOWN` key is part of `Key` object and not `BUTTON`. Here's how -

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(elementVar).perform();
browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).sendKeys(protractor.Key.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(protractor.Key.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(protractor.Key.ARROW_DOWN).perform();
```

For your second try, you should send `RIGHT` in the place of `protractor.Button.ARROW_RIGHT` to right click. When you send two actions/keys to `sendKeys()` function, you have to join them using `chord` object which combines the action of pressing two keys at a time(ex: CTRL+C for copy). But in your case i don't think its really necessary. Here's how to use it -

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(elementVar).perform();
browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord("r", protractor.Key.ENTER).perform(); //Not necessary as you wont be pressing R+ENTER in your keyboard
```

OR

```
browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).sendKeys('R').sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Girish, Thanks, but I tried with both your suggestions but no luck. Below is what I have tried but didn't work:
{browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).sendKeys('R').sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();}
{browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).sendKeys(protractor.Key.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(protractor.Key.ARROW_DOWN).perform()};

Answer (score 0):

use XPath to solve your problem

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(target).perform();
browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform();
element(by.xpath('//*[@id="context-menu"]/ul/li[1]')).click();
```

In your case it will be "//*[@id="context-menu"]/ul/li[3]" most probably.